# How to get the row number of the cell in a for each loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a for each loop like this:

```
Dim rCell as range
Dim Searchrange as range
Set Searchrange = wss.Range("B12:B36") 'where wss is a defined worksheet
For Each rCell in SearchRange
    'do some stuff
    'get the row number of the worksheetrow rCell is currently refering to
Next rCell
```

How do I get the row number from the original worksheet (`wss.`) that `rCell` is currently holding the value of?

Comment: `debug.print rcell.row` perhaps..?

Comment: what about `rCell.Row`? @Jeeped well you beat me by half a second.

Comment: sometimes the hardest things have the simplest solutions. Been bumping my head at this for hours -_-

Comment: It will return a number between 12 and 36 depending on what iteration of the loop you are on.

Comment: While `rCell.Row` returns the absolute row number `rCell.Row - Searchrange.Row + 1` will return the row number relative to the `Searchrange`.

Comment: @Peh, nice explanation. Perhaps consider writing it up as an answer.

Comment: Or @Jeeped, write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 different "row numbers" I can imagine:

1. Absolute row number in the sheet
2. Row number relative to the `Searchrange`

Example:

```
Dim SearchRange As Range
Set SearchRange = wss.Range("B12:B36") 'where wss is a defined worksheet

Dim rCell As Range
For Each rCell in SearchRange
    'Absolute row number in the worksheet
    Debug.Print rCell.Row                          'returns 12, 13, 14, … 36

    'Row number relative to the SearchRange
    Debug.Print rCell.Row - Searchrange.Row + 1    'returns 1, 2, 3, … 25
Next rCell
```